# How to override saveChanges() According to different db tables in EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

e.g i have Teachers and Students tables in both tables have ,created by & updated by fields
which i want to fill in override saveChanges() method,when ever i add any new object of these tables but how i suppose to know which object call "override saveChanges()" please help me
Upto now i hard codded enter table name

public override int SaveChanges()
        {

```
        AppConstants._Teacher.CreatedBy = "waleed";


        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create interface like this:

```
public interface ICreatedBy
{
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

and make your entities implement it.

Then try to do something like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
      foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                .Where(e=>e.Entity is ICreatedBy && 
                                    (e.State == EntityState.Added || 
                                     e.State == EntityState.Modified)))
      {
           ICreatedBy e = (ICreatedBy) entry.Entity;
           e.CreatedOn = "waleed";
      }
      return base.SaveChanges();
 }
```